# Which gfortran compiler flag is associated with the warning "Illegal preprocessor directive"?

Tags: gcc, fortran, gfortran, gcc-warning

When using pFUnit (3.2.9) to test my Fortran code, I get many "Illegal preprocessor directive" warnings, e.g.

```
Warning: Illegal preprocessor directive
/path/to/my/file/test.f90:37:2:

 #line 26 "/path/to/my/file/test.f90"
  1
```

The code compiles and runs fine, so I would like to turn off these warnings, while still seeing other compiler warnings.  Which gfortran compiler flag turns this specific warning off?  I am working with gfortran 7.3.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not the kind of warning that one should turn off because not using a preprocessor has usually very bad consequences on codes that use the most common directives like `#define` and `#if`. And as far as I know it isn't possible to turn it off.

It is much wiser to enable the preprocessor using the `-cpp` flag. Not only the warnings will stop but you will get the correct line numbers in further diagnostics as well, the line numbers will refer to your original code.

Comment: Somehow I thought the `-cpp` flag was on already.  But when I added it the warnings went away, and I agree that properly handling the preprocessor directives is the preferred solution. :)  Thanks!