# Pre-processor directives for multiple Fortran compilers on Windows 10

Tags: r, windows, fortran

On my Windonws 10 (x64) machine, I have been trying to call `Fortran` subroutines in `R` using `.Fortran()` function via `gfortran`. The following example code (`test.f90`) works fine:

**The Example code:**

```
! Computes the square of a number

Subroutine sr1(a,b)
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT::sr1
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES C, REFERENCE, ALIAS:'sr1' :: sr1

implicit none
integer a,b
b = a*a
End Subroutine sr1
```

I compiled code in `gfortran`, which worked fine:

```
gfortran -shared -o test.dll test.f90
```

and then calling this subroutine in `R`:

```
dyn.load("path_to_file/test.dll")
is.loaded("sr1") #Returns TRUE
.Fortran("sr1", a=as.integer(12), b=as.integer(10))
```

**What I would like to do:**

I also have Intel Fortran (`iFORT`) and `Lahay Fortran` compilers installed at my machine. Now, I would like to add pre-processor directives in the above code for these multiple Fortran compilers (so that same `test.f90` file can be used for all compilers).

**What I have tried:**

I found a relevant question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635716/gfortran-pre-processor-directives-for-different-operating-systems), and tried to modify the code (`test_mod.f90`) like follows:

```
! Computes the square of a number

Subroutine sr1(a,b)

#ifdef COMPILER_GF
    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT::sr1
    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES C, REFERENCE, ALIAS:'sr1' :: sr1
#endif

#ifdef COMPILER_IF
    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT, STDCALL ::sr1 
    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DECORATE, ALIAS : 'sr1' :: sr1
    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES REFERENCE :: a,b
#endif

#ifdef COMPILER_LF
    dll_export sr1
#endif

implicit none
integer a,b
b = a*a
End Subroutine sr1
```

I tried to compile the code using:

```
 gfortran -shared -o test_mod.dll test_mod.f90 -DCOMPILER_GF
```

and got this errors:

```
Warning: test_mod.f90:5: Illegal preprocessor directive
Warning: test_mod.f90:8: Illegal preprocessor directive
Warning: test_mod.f90:10: Illegal preprocessor directive
Warning: test_mod.f90:14: Illegal preprocessor directive
Warning: test_mod.f90:16: Illegal preprocessor directive
Warning: test_mod.f90:18: Illegal preprocessor directive
test_mod.f90:17.1:

 dll_export sr1
 1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
```

I am new to Fortran and most probably, made a mess in compilation or adding pre-processor directives in incorrect way. Can someone suggest me how can I fix this issue?

Comment: This is related to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50477689/3157076)?

Comment: Did you mean that I should use -cpp flag? like this:  gfortran -shared -o test_mod.dll test_mod.f90 -cpp

Comment: I tried. At least, it compiled without errors and warnings. But, result is not as expected (i.e. not a square of the first number). Can you reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured out the thing. I fixed the problem and the full credits goes to the comment of @francescalus above :).

The following line at `Windows CMD` created `DLL` without errors and warnings and I am able to read and execute `Fortran` subroutine in `R`.

```
gfortran -shared -o test_mod.dll test_mod.f90 -DCOMPILER_GFORTRAN -cpp
```

Based on @Vladimir's comment, I would like to add that if code file is renamed to `.F90`. Then, it can also be compiled without `-cpp` flag, like follows:

```
 gfortran -shared -o test_mod.dll test_mod.F90 -DCOMPILER_GFORTRAN
```

Comment: Or name the file with capital `F`, but I am not sure if that also works on windows, but it might. I thought there will be some duplicate to close this questions is, but I can't find a good one.

Comment: So, naming the file with .F90 and compiling it gfortran -shared -o test_mod.dll test_mod.f90 -DCOMPILER_GFORTRAN. This is what you meant?

Comment: Yes, with capital F gfortran calls `-cpp` automatically. At least on Linux. But I personally use `.f90` and `-cpp` as you showed above.

Comment: Perfect! You are cool! I can confirm that you are right. It also worked perfectly fine (on Windows10) after renaming to .F90 and without using -cpp flag. So, my question is: which one is preferable? Is it a matter of choice only ?

Comment: I prefer the "explicit is better than implicit" philosophy, so I'd go for the -cpp route.